# Anyone has idea which library is needed to fix this error?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyside

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EZOy.png)

```
from ui_interface import *
########################################################################

########################################################################
# IMPORT Custom widgets
from Custom_Widgets.Widgets import *
# INITIALIZE APP SETTINGS
settings = QSettings()
########################################################################



########################################################################
## MAIN WINDOW CLASS
########################################################################
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
```

I'm having pyside pyqt and all the other libraries downloaded it to run ...
But still no idea what to do with it

Comment: What error? Are you referring to the two lines at the bottom of the screenshot? If that's the case, they are not *errors*, they are *warnings* (there's a *huge* difference, in fact, they are in the "problems" section) and they're also just for pylance (auto completion won't work), but have absolutely nothing to do with the ability of your program to work. As a matter of fact, it's likely that it would just run fine (but since you didn't provide an actual [mre] we cannot be 100% sure). Note that it's better to create a QSettings instance only when the QApplication already exists, not before.

Comment: Also, please ensure that the titles of your posts properly summarize the question, as right now your title says *nothing* about your issue: people that might not be able to help you would still need to open it in order to understand it (and that's very annoying), while others just tend to ignore posts that have titles so vague and cryptic. Please take your time to read [ask] and review the [checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648).